# Capturing error logs in the email notification while deploying through octopus deploy

Tags: email, notifications, octopus-deploy

I am using octopus deploy automation tool(V2020 1.14) for deploying my code.Email configuration through SMTP is already configured. Now while email is sent it should have the complete error log in case if deployment is failed at certain step. Could you please share me some thoughts how to do this ???

Comment: Hey, can you please be more specific and clear about your requirements to ease our understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things you could do here but the first thing that comes to mind is this example [here](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/steps/email-notifications#including-step-status) which logs the error and error detail for each step that failed in a deployment.

To extend this further you could add a link to the full deployment log in the email by using other Octopus system variables. To create a link to the deployment the email step is running I've created an example below.

**#{Octopus.Web.ServerUri}/app#/#{Octopus.Space.Id}/projects/#{Octopus.Project.Id}/releases/#{Octopus.Release.Number}/deployments/#{Octopus.Deployment.Id}?activeTab=taskSummary**

Hopefully, this answers your question but if you need further information let me know.